# Grant MonitorAdmin / PROCESS privilege to user

Tags: mariadb, permissions, mariadb-10.3

I need to assign the monitoradmin privilege to a user because this is what an application called "dynatrace" needs to monitor the server (some details in a [post](https://answers.dynatrace.com/spaces/482/dynatrace-open-qa/questions/177408/permissions-for-mysql-monitoring-extension.html) on their site).

According to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/ there is a `PROCESS` privilege but I can't assign it.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER dynatrace IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.007 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT MonitorAdmin TO dynatrace;
ERROR 1959 (OP000): Invalid role specification `MonitorAdmin`
```

Same result with `PROCESS`:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT PROCESS TO dynatrace;
ERROR 1959 (OP000): Invalid role specification `PROCESS`
```

Where is my mistake ? Although my knowledge about mariaDB is more than limited I have the password of the root account ;-) and can run the commands as this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general monitoring, this comes closer to covering all bases, but without being able to "cause damage":

```
GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, REFERENCES, SHOW DATABASES,
      REPLICATION CLIENT, SHOW VIEW
      ON *.* TO username@'...';
```

The `ON *.*` is necessary (though clumsy) syntax.

If the *data* is sensitive, remove `SELECT`.  It can even be argued that being able to list the database names (`SHOW DATABASES`) could be sensitive.

`REPLICATION CLIENT` (not `SLAVE`) let's you monitor `Seconds_behind_master` in a Slave.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#global-privileges):

> To set a global privilege, use *.* for priv_level.

So your command should be

```
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO dynatrace;
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
GRANT PROCESS, SELECT ON *.* TO dynatrace;
```

Comment: In which way is the `GRANT` better than that from LowlyDBAs answer ? Would I miss something if I don't grant `SELECT`

Comment: @Marged - It depends on what you need to monitor.  Another example: 
 `REPLICATION CLIENT` is handy for `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`.